# Animating contentOffset changes in a UICollectionView on deleteItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, contentsize, contentoffset

I have a `UICollectionView` to which cells can be added and removed. I'm making these changes using `performBatchUpdates`, and the layout is animating as expected.

The problem comes when I scroll to the end of the content and delete an item such that the `contentSize` decreases: This causes the `contentOffset` to change, but the change isn't animated. Instead, the `contentOffset` jumps immediately after the deletion animation completes. I've tried manually updating the `contentOffset` alongside the deletion but that didn't work for me either.

I'm using a custom layout, but I see the same behaviour with a standard flow layout, using the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)addItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    self.runningCount++;
    [self.items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %u",self.runningCount]];
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count-1 inSection:0]]];
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but this has me stumped.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but I wonder if you encountered a similar situation where deleting an item such that `contentSize` shrinks & the view scrolls results in the scrolled-into-view items not appearing until after the deletion animation finished? The code to reproduce is almost identical to what you've posted, so I figured you must have seen it too? I've [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25528337/429427) explaining it; I'd be really grateful if you had time to take a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The animation glitch is seen where the `contentSize` of the collection view shrinks such that its height or width becomes smaller than (or equal to) that of the collection view bounds.

It's possible to force the expected animation in the batch update block using `setContentOffset:animated:` and similar, but this relies on knowing the projected content size after deletion. Content size is managed by the collection view layout, but since we haven't actually deleted the cell yet, we can't just ask the layout (or we'd get the old size).

To work around this I implemented the `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:` method in my custom layout to adjust the content offset as desired. The code below, which only accounts for Y offset, was sufficient for my needs:

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset
{
    if (self.collectionViewContentSize.height <= self.collectionView.bounds.size.height)
    {
        return CGPointMake(proposedContentOffset.x,0);
    }
    return proposedContentOffset;
}
```

I tried this out in a direct UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass and it does the job there too.

Comment: Good find. I just encountered this problem myself, and this solution did the trick (maybe worth mentioning that `contentInset` might need to be accounted for if it is non-zero). It seems odd that the default implementation of `targetContentOffset...` doesn't catch this case - I'll submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

this works well for me，quoted from [the question discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528337/deleting-cell-at-edge-of-uicollectionview-cells-not-appearing-immediately-afte)

```
[self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]]];
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
} completion:nil];
```